# Keyword Extractor for Query Strings

Tags: php, query-string

I've found a few keyword extractors for query strings, but they all seem to be outdated (use deprecated code or simply don't work).

Does anyone know of a php query string extractor.  Or how would I build a function that takes a "host" like "amazon.com" and the names of multiple query parameters and returns the values of those parameters?

For instance, `http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=a+tale+of+two+cities&x=0&y=0`

If I provided "amazon.com" and "field-keywords" how can I get the array: `['a','tale','of','two','cities']`  ?

Thanks in advance!!

**Clarification**

Jose's answer covers my example for Amazon but doesn't seem to work for any other URL:

`http://www.bing.com/search?q=Christmas+Around+The+World&form=QBLH&qs=PN&sk=HS1PN4&pq=&sp=6&sc=8-0`

`http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=AnQN0c997QR5SIYcYt.h2YCbvZx4?p=golf&toggle=1&cop=mss&ei=UTF-8&fr=yfp-t-701`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (I) could write one.

```
function getValueFromDomain($urls, $domain, $key) {
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        if (preg_match('/https?:\/\/[^\/]*?' . preg_quote($domain) . '\//', $url)) {
            parse_str(substr($url, strpos($url, '?') + 1), $output);
            if (isset($output[$key])) {
                $array = explode(' ', $output[$key]);
                return $array;
            }
        }
    }
    return array();
}
```

Just a tad of code stolen from @Jose's answer :)

**Update**: tested, didn't work, fixed, works.

**Update 2**: didn't work after all, tested, fixed, works.

**Update 3**: added support for HTTPS

Comment: Oh hey @Jonah!  Sorry, didn't see that you updated.  Problem with this one (as I understand it) is that if the key I'm looking for doesn't come directly after the '?' (for instance if there are multiple keys) then it won't be set.  True?

Comment: No, it works perfectly.  I was saying that was a problem with @Jose's solution.

Comment: @Jonah, 
`$url = http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch?date_select=full&query=tiger&type=nyt&x=0&y=0
parse_str(substr($url, strpos($url, '?') + 1), $output);`
$output returns `{"date_select":"full"}`

Comment: I ran it and it returns `{"date_select":"full", "query":"tiger", "type":"nyt", "x":"0", "y":"0"}`.  What do you mean?

Comment: Oh perfect!!  Sorry, my fault.  I was feeding it encoded URLs.  Awesome function!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it..

```
<?php
    $str = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=a+tale+of+two+cities&x=0&y=0";
    parse_str($str, $output);
    $array =  explode(" ",$output['field-keywords']);
    print_r($array);

?>
```

Comment: Good, but the OP wants to be able to search an array of URLs for a specific domain, and get the value from it.  Half way there.

Comment: @Emile: try `parse_url()` instead: se.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: I like this answer but it's not working for any other URLs besides the amazon example.  I provided a bing and a yahoo example above.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Emile: parse_url explodes a string at `&`.  Bing and Yahoo put the query as the first parameter.  You need to change `parse_str($str,...` to how it is in my answer.

Comment: @Jonah, it seems I need a combination of the two :)

Answer (score 0):

The way I read the question, you would only need the query string index name to be passed to the function like...

```
function get_keywords($parameter){
        $words = explode(" ", $_GET[$parameter]);
         return $words;
}
```